# Is it possible to use app url scheme as NSURL in FBSDKShareLinkContent

Tags: ios9, facebook-sdk-4.0, fbsdksharekit

We can post the link content by using the code:

```
 FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
content.contentURL =
[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
content.contentTitle=@"Sample app Teja";
content.contentDescription=@"Please click on this message or post or link";

[FBSDKMessageDialog showWithContent:content delegate:self];
```

As sharing the plain text is not possible I tried to replace the contentURL with my app url-scheme,

```
  content.contentURL =[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb1709123452649://"];
```

and I get the error:

> Error Occured:Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.share Code=2 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorArgumentValueKey=
>   fb1709123452649://,
>   com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Invalid value for
>   contentURL: fb1709123452649://,
>   com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorArgumentNameKey=contentURL}

Is it possible to convert the app url to NSURL ?